# Customizing Route Key Name not working

Tags: laravel

I'd like model binding to use a table column other than `id` when retrieving a given model, and I override `getKeyName` in Model class (`Service` in this case) but it's not working!

```
class Service extends Model{
   //override
   public function getRouteKey() {
       return 'key';
   }
}
```

Service table:

```
id  |  key(string,unique)  |  name(string)
```

my routes file:

```
Route::resource('services', 'ServiceController');
```

and in `ServiceController`:

```
public function show(Service $service) {
    return $service;
}
```

but when I go to `mysiteurl.com/services/vps` it shows the 404 page.
(`mysiteurl.com/services/1` works but I don't want to use id column in URL)

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: You need to rename your method to `getRouteKeyName` and not `getRouteKey`.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want Laravel to bind your model to a route with a value other than the model's ID, you need to override the `getRouteKeyName()` method like so:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```